# Why torque on current carrying circular loop in uniform magnetic field is differs from results of $\mu \times \vec{B}$ if we apply calculus method

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

We have a current carrying circular wire kept in uniform magnetic field $\vec{B}$, as shown, I tried to derive the torque $\vec{\tau}$ acting on it
[image]

For 2 elemental parts on wire subtending angle $d\theta$ at center right at opposite to each other

$$d\vec{\tau} = 2idl B \sin\theta r$$
it gives

$$\tau = -2i
  r^2 \cos \theta$$

on varying $\theta$ from $0$ to $\pi$ I get net torque $\tau = 4ir^2\times B$

but by applying $\tau = I\vec{A}\times\vec {B}$

Note- Here $r$ is radius of wire, there is a factor of 2 because they are 2 elemental parts situated just opposite to each other .Torque on both elemental parts would have same magnitude and would add up ,I replaced $dl$ with $rd\theta$
.Angle $\theta$ is shown in pic.

I got another answer $\tau = I\pi r^2 B$, which is correct

I don't know why there is so much differences in answers , although both processes look correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually two cross-products, and you've ignored one of them.

I'm going to assume that the magnetic field is in the plane of the loop, pointing along $\mathbf{\hat{y}}$, while the loop is in the $xy-$plane.

The infinitesimal torque is given by $$\text{d}\boldsymbol{\tau} = \text{d}\mathbf{F}\times \mathbf{r}.$$

The infinitesimal force is $\text{d}\mathbf{F} = I \text{d}\mathbf{l}\times\mathbf{B}$.

As you've pointed out, $$\text{d}\mathbf{F} = I B r\,\,\text{d}\theta \sin{\theta}\, \mathbf{\hat{z}}$$

So far, what you've done seems correct. (You can verify that the net force on the wire is indeed $0$ by integrating over $\theta$.)  However, when you calculate the infinitesimal torque, you need to find

$$\text{d}\boldsymbol{\tau} = \text{d}\mathbf{F}\times \mathbf{r} = I B r \sin{\theta}\text{d}\theta \mathbf{\hat{z}}\times (r \cos{\theta} \mathbf{\hat{x}} + r\sin{\theta} \mathbf{\hat{y}} ),$$

where in the last step I've written $\mathbf{r} = r \cos{\theta} \mathbf{\hat{x}} + r\sin{\theta} \mathbf{\hat{y}}.$ Expanding this, we have two terms. It can be easily shown (I'll leave it as an exercise) that one of those terms integrates to $0$ as $\theta$ runs from $[0,2\pi)$, and the other term gives you

$$\boldsymbol{\tau} = -\mathbf{\hat{x}} I B r^2 \int_0^{2\pi}\sin^2\theta\, \text{d}\theta =  -I \pi r^2 B\, \mathbf{\hat{x}},$$

which is exactly what you'd get if you calculated it using $$\boldsymbol{\tau} = I \mathbf{A}\times\mathbf{B} = I \pi r^2 B \mathbf{\hat{z}}\times \mathbf{\hat{y}} = - I \pi r^2 B \mathbf{\hat{x}}.$$

Comment: I understood what you have done, But my question is I why can't we take $r\cos\theta \vec{x} + r\sin \theta \vec{y}$ as a resultant vector of $\vec{r}$ then the direction of $\tau$ would be along a tangential vector perpendicular to $\vec{r}$

Comment: I didn't ignore any cross product, you have taken components of radius vector $r \cos \theta$  and $r \sin \theta$, I have taken the whole radius vector because it has constant magnitude, and the net direction of $d\vec{\tau}$ would have same magnitude and direction (tangential) at that elemental part, as it is verified by you as well @Philip please answer.

Comment: As I've pointed out, the magnitude of the radius is constant, but the direction of the radius vector changes as you go around the loop, and therefore so does the contribution to the torque. For example, consider an element at the 3 o'clock position of your loop. In this case, $\mathbf{r}$ is along $\mathbf{x}$, and $\mathbf{z}\times\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{y}$. Alternatively, consider an element at 12 o'clock: in this case, $\mathbf{z}\times\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{z}\times\mathbf{y} = -\mathbf{x}$. I've taken into account how the direction of the radius vector changes as we integrate around the loop.

Comment: @maverick What I'm basically saying is that up until you write $$\text{d}\boldsymbol{\tau} = \left(I r^2 B \sin\theta \boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}}\,\right)\text{d}\theta,$$ you're correct. However [the unit vectors in polar coordinates are not independent of $\theta$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector#Cylindrical_coordinates)! So treating it like a constant vector is wrong, and this is what leads to your error. You need to take into account the variation of $\boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}}$ with $\theta$.

Comment: thank you so much I forgot that the contribution of components of radius vector is changing, so  the direction of torque is changing although the torque has same magnitude. your answer really helped me a lot